# Can I use my non-WAAS GPS receiver with ADS-B in the United States?

Tags: air-traffic-control, gnss, ads-b

I have a older style Garmin 530.  Can I use this GPS as the position source for an ADS-B installation?

Comment: I'm trying to find the FAA requirement but you must have an ADS-B certified WAAS GPS source for your ADS-B transceiver.

Comment: Garmin still offers an upgrade of the 530 to 530W. It is $3,995 for the upgrade. There will be some additional costs from the shop for replacing the antenna. The upside is that you can buy a cheaper ADS-B unit since the 530 can provide position info. https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/597181

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the USA, ADS-B requires a WAAS position source. A Garmin 530**W** can be used, but not a 530.

Here's a [full list](http://www.faa.gov/nextgen/equipadsb/equipment/) of FAA certified equipment needed for ADS-B. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a WAAS GPS source if you need to comply with the ADS-B mandate but there are quite a few GA pilots who only fly VFR in regions where the ADS-B mandate does not apply.

It is permissable to use a non WAAS GPS source with your transponder if you wish to voluntarily transmit ADS-B in airspace where the mandate does not apply.  The FAA and EASA seem to have gone out of their way to conceal that fact.