# Will a non-certified GPS source work the same in ADS-B mandated airspace?

Tags: ads-b, gnss

What happens if you use a non-WAAS GPS position source in ADS-B mandated airspace? Doesn't it work the same, except for the positional accuracy?

Comment: Are you asking about non-certified, or non-waas? Those are two very different things...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking here and if there's even any answer. Are you asking if you could use a non-WAAS GPS unit as a position source for an ADS/B out unit? If so, are you asking if it's possible technically or legally? If legally, in which country? And if you're new to the site, the [tour] may be helpful.

Comment: Related : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29798/can-i-use-my-non-waas-gps-receiver-with-ads-b-in-the-united-states?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may work. It may not work. Nobody knows. If you use a non-certify equipment when you are required to use the certified one you are breaking the law. Nobody can be sure your equipment will work as required but everybody are sure you are breaking the law.

Don't do it. You are endangering your life and others.